# Route 53 health checks marked healthy even if they are only reachable by 18% of health checkers. Can this 18% threshold be adjusted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

According to the Amazon Route 53 documentation, an endpoint will be marked as healthy if it is reported as such by more than 18% of health checkers.

We had a specific scenario last week where an outage at Google caused Google Load Balancers to gradually decline in availability from 100% accessible to being accessible by only about 20% of AWS health checkers.

The desired behavior would have been to have marked this health check as unhealthy, but it seems the health check is designed to only trigger if the availability drops below 18%. Is there any way to adjust this 18% number higher?

From Amazon Route 53 Documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html):

> Each Amazon Route 53 health checker propagates the results of its health checks to Amazon Route 53 DNS servers worldwide. If more than 18% of available health checkers report that an endpoint is healthy, Amazon Route 53 responds to queries using the associated resource record sets when applicable. If 18% of health checkers or fewer report that an endpoint is healthy, Amazon Route 53 typically does not respond to queries using the associated resource record sets. The 18% value might change in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no configuration option** for modifying how Route 53 Health Checkers operate.

One option is to **create your own health check**. For example, a web server could check whether it can connect to a database. Create a special page on the web server (eg `example.com/health.htm`) that does the check and returns a 'success' message. Then, configure Route 53 to look for that message as part of the health check.

See [String Matching documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating.html#health-checks-creating-values-string-matching).